# ¿Como validar valores nulos de Excel en C#?

Tags: c#, excel, null

Estoy trabajando con un controlador, he llegado al punto en dónde me recibe el archivo de Excel el controlador. He creado una clase y ahí gestione todas las columnas con su respectivo tipo de datos.

En mi archivo algunas columnas están nulas, no contienen datos. Entonces necesito saber una forma de validar mis columnas, tengo una manera de como podría ser pero no me ejecuta la petición. Las columnas string no las valido porque soportan ir nulas, tengo entendido.

```
listVMOpexBanco.Add(new VMOpexBanco
                    {
                        LineaMc = ws.Cell(row, 1).Value.ToString().Trim(),
                        LineaNivel2 = ws.Cell(row, 2).Value.ToString().Trim(),
                        LineaNivel3 = ws.Cell(row, 3).Value.ToString().Trim(),
                        LineaNivel4 = ws.Cell(row, 4).Value.ToString().Trim(),
                        Banco = (int?)((ws.Cell(row, 5).Value != null) ? Convert.ToInt32(ws.Cell(row, 5).ToString().Trim()) : (ws.Cell(row, 5).Value = null))});
```

Comment: Que librería estas usando para leer excel?

Comment: Estoy utilizando ClosedXML.

Comment: Publica la clase VMOpexBanco

Comment: deberias editar tu pregunta, y mostrar el tipo de dato que deseas evaluar, porque un string se puede evaluar mediante `string,isnullorempty(mystring)`, y un listado mediante `any()`, un entero, siempre sera `0`, igualmente, se podria agregar en tu listado que sean Nullables y que tu controlador pueda recibir los campos null sin problema

Comment: Al final pude solucionar. Los formatos que no son string los pude convertir y ahí finalmente el controlador me recibe el nombre del archivo que quiero cargar. Igual los valide para que me acepte null.